# I've planned my visit for years vs I've been planning my visit for years

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-aspect

Look at these two sentences:

I've planned my visit to Japan for years.
I've been planning my visit to Japan for years.

To me, both are acceptable and interchangeable. Would I be incorrect? Both of these examples use "for" (duration), indicating an unfinished timeframe.
Edit: My reference is Michael Swan's Practical English Usage, page 421, where he says "Generally, however, both progressive and simple tenses are possible like these, with a slight difference of emphasis" [image]

Comment: I would find the continuous tense far more natural here, though I can't say that the other is wrong.

Comment: On reflection _I've planned my visit_ could mean 'I've thought for years that it would  be good to go to Japan some day_ and _I've been planning my visit_ means 'I've been actively making plans'.

Comment: Thanks Kate ! Much appreciated.